# Send data to server in javascript (tcp like)

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I would like to send data in javascript to a server. Normally one would use Ajax, but in my case the server will be a part of a small c application. Thus, I want it to be very small, similiar to the direct use of TCP sockets. Unfortunately, one cannot just use TCP sockets in javascript. So what would be the best lightweight solution (where is no need of any installation)?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, one cannot initiate TCP connections from browser at their own will. The nearest allowed thing is [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). According to websocket protocol, defined in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), they use HTTP handshake to initiate the session and then exchange data on the top of TCP.

Key differences from TCP:

- 2-14 bytes of additional headers
- message borders are preserved (one send needs one receive)
- maximum message size is 2^64
- has its own fragmentation mechanism
- there's a secure (encrypted) version of this protocol